# beautifulsoup vs re and searches with regext

Tags: python, regex, search, beautifulsoup

I use urllib2.urlopen to get the source code of sites like [this](http://descartes.cnice.mec.es/grupodescartes/Galo/eXe/Escenas_macros/Escenas_macros.html).
I read the bytes and I get the code labeled as applet using beautifulsoup.
This code includes lines as:

```
<param name="G_00" value="espacio='E1' tipo='macro' expresi&oacute;n='dinamica/resorte'">
```

I need to capture all the "expresión=" values in the code that are included in values with *tipo="macro"* (*dinamica/resorte* and *dinamica/masa* specifically).

With beautifulsoup I identify these kind of lines as tags, only tags with tipo='macro' well, I want to be brief, now I look for the right side of *expresión=*  :

```
key_macro = ['expresión=', 'expresion=', 'expresi&oacute;n='....] # yes, a problem, it could be this way
for y in key_macro:
    if string.find(tag, y) != -1:
        # sometimes -sorry- macros are in txt format: 
        mexpression = r"%s'([\w\./]+)'" % y
        mpatron = re.compile(mexpression)
        mresult = mpatron.search(tag['value'])
        if mresult: # 1
            macroslist.append(mresult.group(1))
        # sometimes without extension
        wexpression = r"%s'([\w/]+)'" % y
        wpatron = re.compile(wexpression)
        wresult = wpatron.search(tag['value'])
        if wresult: # 2
            macroslist.append(wresult.group())
```

**The problem**: with #1 I get the .txt file if it exists -I can assure- BUT with # 2 (I look for word/word) I do not find somethings as dinamica/resorte, wresult is always failed, and I need to capture these values.

Is my regexp bad?. All the problem is how to indicate word/word with a regexp?

I tried the search with beautifulsoup but 'macro' is INSIDE value, and I don't know how to capture this tags, anyway re + search seem to do a good job (...while the right side be: dinamica/resorte.txt for example, then # 1 it works) but not whithout the extension.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the brute-force and stupid solution, but you should specify your needs better with respect of what all keys you may want to search for.  I personally do not consider the solution good.  Anyway, try:

```
import re

def brute_force_and_stupid(s, rex=re.compile(r"expresion='([a-zA-Z./]+)'")):
    s = s.replace('&oacute;', 'o')
    s = s.replace('ó', 'o')
    print s
    m = rex.search(s)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
    return None

tag = "<param name=\"G_00\" value=\"espacio='E1' tipo='macro' expresi&oacute;n='dinamica/resorte'\">"
print tag
print brute_force_and_stupid(tag)
```

It prints on my console:

```
c:\tmp\___python\Antonio\so10295276>python a.py
<param name="G_00" value="espacio='E1' tipo='macro' expresi&oacute;n='dinamica/resorte'">
<param name="G_00" value="espacio='E1' tipo='macro' expresion='dinamica/resorte'">
dinamica/resorte
```

Slightly better solution with a more complex regular expression.  (Notice the unicode strings here.)

```
import re

rex = re.compile(ur"expresi(o|ó|&oacute;)n='(?P<text>[a-zA-Z./]+)'")

tag = u"<param name=\"G_00\" value=\"espacio='E1' tipo='macro' expresi&oacute;n='dinamica/resorte'\">"
print tag

m = rex.search(tag)
if m:
    print m.group('text')
else:
    print None
```

It prints:

```
c:\tmp\___python\Antonio\so10295276>python b.py
<param name="G_00" value="espacio='E1' tipo='macro' expresi&oacute;n='dinamica/resorte'">
dinamica/resorte
```

Comment: ja!, second idea (look for (?P<text>[a-zA-Z./]+) converting to unicode the patron and the tag previously seem to work perfectly!. Sorry for my bad explanations and thank you for you effort to undertand. Yes, regex produces headaches.